# Componet Template and linked schema details in Tridion 2011 tables

Tags: tridion-2011

We want extract all the Component templates and Linked schema details. Could any one please let me know script to extract these details from Tridion 2011 database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest posting this at https://tridion.stackexchange.com/

The easiest way to extract data from SDL Tridion is to use the content Porter. You could export all of the Components and their dependencies as a package. Butr without more information on what you want to do with the data it is hard to know if this would meet your requirements.

IN the old [PowerTools](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/powertools.aspx) there was a tool which gave an overview of what you wanted, but I don't  know if it worked with 2011 (I guess not). You may be able to adapt one of the old script from there if you are in a rush. Otherwise I suggest using the Core Service API to just get all of the CTs for a publication, and create a report on their data yourself.

Comment: Thanks for advice Chris. I have used content porter to import all the CT's details and created utility to read it from imported xmls. I got the required information.

Comment: If this helped, you might consider voting for and/or accepting the answer.